# Retrieving distinct relationships of relationships using Eloquent in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Lets assume I have a model for: **Race**, **Participant**, **Team**
And these relations: **Race** `1-N` **Participant** `N-1` **Team**

See in another way :

```
races  1 - N  participants
teams  1 - N  participants
```

In Laravel terms:

```
/* Inside Race model */
public function participants()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Participant::class);
}


/* Inside Team model */
public function participants()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Participant::class);
}


/* Inside Participant model */
public function race()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Race::class);
}
public function team()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Team::class);
}
```

In the `participants` table, It looks like this:

```
id | team_id | race_id | [a lot of other columns...]
------------------------------
 1 |    1    |    1    |
 2 |    1    |    1    |
 3 |    2    |    1    |
 4 |    2    |    1    |
```

In the above example, I know that the race `ID 1` has `2 teams`.

I can `count` them by doing this:

```
$race = Race::find(1);
$number = $race->participants()->distinct()->count('team_id');
```

### The problem

`Counting` the number of teams is cool, but I want to access to the list of corresponding `Team` model instances, so that I can use them for further operations (within a `foreach` loop for example).
I tried a lot of things without success.
Something like this:

```
$teams = $race->participants()->distinct()->[...] // Don't know what to put here
```

The working equivalent SQL query is:

```
SELECT teams.* FROM teams
INNER JOIN participants ON participants.team_id = teams.id
INNER JOIN races ON races.id = participants.race_id
WHERE races.id = 1
GROUP BY teams.id
```

Resulting in this:

[image: teams query]

When the `participants` table contains this:

[image: participant query]

I want to know if I can do it with `Eloquent` instead of using `Query/Builder DB::` methods directly ?

### EDIT 1

My closest result:

```
$race->participants()->distinct()->get('team_id')
```

[image: result 1]

And then using this list of `team_id` I can access to the teams using `Team::find([list of IDs])` but it looks greedy to me.

### EDIT 2

I forgot some information:

- The `participants.team_id` column is `NULLABLE` because:

  - There are `races` with `teams` of `participants`
  - There are `races` with `participants` (without `team`)

Comment: Just so I understand your relations, A race can have many teams & a team can have many participants. Correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct. I edited my question to add more information about what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's improve your eloquent relations.

```
// Race
public function teams()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Team::class);
}
public function withoutTeamParticipants() // change name that suits you
{
    return $this->hasMany(Participant::class);
}


// Team
public function participants()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Participant::class); // In this case make sure that participant.race_id is null
}


// Participant
public function team()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Team::class); // When no team, then participant.team_id is null
}
public function race()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Race::class);
}
```

To access list of participants of a given race:

```
$race = Race::where('id', 1)->with('teams.participants', 'withoutTeamParticipants')->get();
```

In your blade you can further use this as:

```
// List of participants without a team
@foreach ($race->withoutTeamParticipants as $participant)
    {{ $participant->name }}
@endforeach

// List of participants that are with a team
@foreach ($race->teams as $team)
    @foreach ($team->participants as $participant)
        {{ $participant->name }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Putting a  `$this->hasMany(Team::class)` inside the `Race` model suggests that the `teams.race_id` column exists. But It currently doesn't in my DB structure.

Comment: Then I highly suggest to add one. Based on the relationship, that is the right way to do it.

Comment: Do you suggest I should add a `race_id` inside the `teams` table ? It would mean that I have `teams.race_id` and `participants.race_id`. It looks like duplicate to me, right ?

Comment: `team.race_id` and `participant.team_id`

Comment: I must have a `participants.race_id` column because `races` may have no `teams`. `participants.team_id` is `NULLABLE`. (I may add this information to my question).

Comment: There are races with teams of participants.
And, there are races with participants (without team).

Comment: Yes, please update the question with that info. I will also update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can easily access to it through the `$race` instance.
But, you can use the `whereHas` method on the `Team` model:

```
$race = Race::find(1);
$teams = Team::whereHas('participants', function ($query) use ($race) {
    $query->where('race_id', $race->id);
})->get();  // ->count() also works
```

[See documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

Answer (score 2):

To get distinct teams from a race model, you could add a [many to many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) between `Race` and `Team` with `Participant` acting as the pivot.

For example,

```
/* Race */
public function teams()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Team::class, 'participants', 'race_id', 'team_id');
}


/* Team */
public function races()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Race::class,'participants', 'team_id', 'race_id');
}
```

Then, you could just do this

```
$race = Race::find($id);
$teams = $race->teams()->distinct()->get();
```

to get a list of distinct teams for the race.

And since we set up the relationship on both models, you can now also get distinct races for each team by doing

```
$team = Team::find($id);
$teams = $team->races()->distinct()->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use hasManyThrough relationship inside Race model for fetching distinct teams associated with the race.

```
public function distinctTeams()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Team::class, Participant::class, 'race_id', 'id', 'id', 'team_id')->distinct();
}
```

Now, you can loop over the teams of a race by using $race->distinctTeams

Hopefully this helps.